# Is Parameter Group Valid for Binding

Tags: revit-api

I'm using the Revit API to bind some shared parameters in.  I'm trying to give the user a list of possible groups to display in and let them choose one for the parameters to go in.  I can get this list pretty easily like this:

```
foreach (var typeId in ParameterUtils.GetAllBuiltInGroups())
{
    ...create my objects...
}
```

However, this creates a larger list than the one in the Revit parameter binding dialog so there are things there that are not actually available.  I can bind them using these groups and it binds without error but when I try to edit the group is blank in the Revit UI.

Is there a way to determine if a group is actually usable?